# When should I use std::async with sync as policy?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11

std::async has an overload which takes a std::launch policy as the first argument. When should I use this overload? what are the different policies available? (I think sync and async are the two options). When should I use the sync policy? How is that different from directly running it?

Comment: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html ---> This could be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary from [the very helpful article that Jagannath linked](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html), and comments on the possible uses.

There are 3 launch policies:

- `any`: the library chooses whether to spawn a thread a or not
- `async`: you explicitly ask for a thread to be spawned
- `deferred`: you explicitly ask for a thread **not** to be spawned

Therefore, the `deferred` policy is a way to get **deterministic lazy evaluation** (also known as call by need). For example, suppose that you have:

```
void MyClass::lazy(std::future<int> const& f) {
  if (this->notReady()) { return; }
  if (this->stillNotReady()) { return; }
  if (this->value() == 42) { return; }

  this->go(f.get());
}
```

Now, if computing the value of this integer is *long* (for example, it may invoke a network roundtrip), then it's kinda wasteful to compute it in all the cases that do not really require it... and now we've got the tool to do so!

```
void func(MyClass& mc) {
  std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []() {
                         return stoi(memcached.get("KEY"));
                       });

  mc.lazy(f);
}
```

Note that this is *subtly different* from using a `std::function<int()>` (and a closure), because the computation is done *once and for all*, guaranteeing that subsequent calls to get always return the same result.

The difference with the other policies can also be expressed in term of whether the operation is performed *when you do not need the value*.

- `any`: might be performed on another thread (proactively) or not performed at all
- `async`: will be performed on another thread
- `deferred`: will **not** be performed

Therefore, `deferred` gives you better control, which is important if the call has a side effect.

Comment: "sync" is actually `std::launch::deferred`

Comment: @Cubbi: thanks for pointing out, I should have cross-checked with the Standard.

Comment: "subsequent calls to `get()`" will invoke undefined behavior, since `get()` invalidates the `future`.  You'd need a `shared_future` to avoid the invalidation.